# Updated data is not showing in the view (MVC 5, EF, SQL Dependency)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqldependency

I want to display the updated data in the view from the database. I am using output caching with sql dependency.

Below is the controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult List()
{
    var project = unitOfWork.ProjectRepository
                            .Get().AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == 0)
                            .Select(p => new Project { ProjectID = p.ProjectID, Name = p.Name })
                            .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                            .ToList();

    string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(project);

    return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `web.config`:

```
<caching>
    <sqlCacheDependency enabled="true" pollTime="2000">
        <databases>
            <add name="DSS" connectionStringName="DocumentStorageContext"/>
        </databases>
    </sqlCacheDependency>
</caching>
```